# Using filter in dplyr to generate values for all rows

Tags: r, dplyr

```
library(tidyverse)
library(nycflights13)
nycflights13::flights
```

If the following expression gives flights per day from the dataset:

```
daily <- dplyr::group_by( flights, year, month, day)
(per_day <- dplyr::summarize( daily, flights = n()))
```

I wanted something similar for cancelled flights:

```
canx <- dplyr::filter( flights, is.na(dep_time) & is.na(arr_time))
canx2 <- canx %>% dplyr::group_by( year, month, day)
```

My goal was to have the same length of data frame as for all summarised flights.

I can get number of flights cancelled per day:

```
(canx_day <- dplyr::summarize( canx2, flights = n()))
```

but obviously this is a slightly shorter data frame, so I cannot run e.g.:

```
canx_day$propcanx <- per_day$flights/canx_day$flights
```

Even if I introduce NAs I can replace them.

So my question is, should I not be using filter, or are there arguments to filter I should be applying?

Many thanks

Comment: Is there a column as `Cancelled` to mark canceled flight? If yes then your job is very easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be using `filter`. As others suggest, this is easy with a `canceled` column, so our first step will be to create that column. Then you can easily get whatever you want with a single `summarize`. For example:

```
flights %>% 
    mutate(canceled = as.integer(is.na(dep_time) & is.na(arr_time))) %>%
    group_by(year, month, day) %>%
    summarize(n_scheduled = n(),
              n_not_canceled = sum(!canceled),
              n_canceled = sum(canceled),
              prop_canceled = mean(canceled))
# # A tibble: 365 x 7
# # Groups:   year, month [?]
#     year month   day n_scheduled n_not_canceled n_canceled prop_canceled
#    <int> <int> <int>       <int>          <int>      <int>         <dbl>
#  1  2013     1     1         842            838          4   0.004750594
#  2  2013     1     2         943            935          8   0.008483563
#  3  2013     1     3         914            904         10   0.010940919
#  4  2013     1     4         915            909          6   0.006557377
#  5  2013     1     5         720            717          3   0.004166667
#  6  2013     1     6         832            831          1   0.001201923
#  7  2013     1     7         933            930          3   0.003215434
#  8  2013     1     8         899            895          4   0.004449388
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives you flights and canceled flight per day by `flight, year, month, day`

```
nycflights13::flights %>% 
  group_by(flight, year, month, day) %>% 
  summarize(per_day = n(),
            canx = sum(ifelse(is.na(arr_time), 1, 0)))
```

Answer (score -2):

There is a simple way to calculate number of flights canceled per day. Lets assume that `Cancelled` column is `TRUE` for the cancelled flight. If so then way to calculate daily canceled flights will be:

```
flights %>%
group_by(year, month, day) %>%
summarize( canx_day = sum(Cancelled))
```

`canx_day` will contain canceled flights for a day.

Comment: Please provide comments with -ve votes. The solution above answers question from OP on use of `filter` and shows a way to calculate canceled a flight with an assumption of a `Cancelled` column. Even the accepted solution has taken same approach but included way add a `canceled` column.

Comment: Didn't downvote, but the data is provided (in a package loaded in the question), so it's easy to see that there is no "canceled" column. You don't directly address OP's stated question (*"So my question is, should I not be using filter, or are there arguments to filter I should be applying?"*), and the OP demonstrates in the question that they can get the number of canceled flights, the main obstacle seems to be getting to the proportion of canceled flights. For you or me, that is a simple extension, but for OP it's part of the problem.

Comment: From my perspective, those are reasons to *not upvote* rather than to *downvote*, but different people have different standards. Some combination of those factors is my best guess as to why you are drawing downvotes.

Comment: @Gregor Thanks for sharing your views and I agree with your points. As I had mentioned earlier that my point of view was that there is difficulty in counting, hence provided a solution with assumption. Upvote/downvote doesn't matter much as long I'm able to help. Probably I would not have posted a solution if your solution was already there, as you have explained it very clearly.

Comment: Yeah, I saw your solution as I was finishing up writing mine. As the basic method is the same, I thought about not posting it, but I thought my explanation would be clearer for OP.